# Nodejs Equivalent PHP semaphore functions

Tags: php, node.js, semaphore

Is there anyway to implemented php semaphore functions in Nodejs

For ex `resource msg_get_queue ( int $key [, int $perms = 0666 ] )`

how can we perform the task of this function using nodejs

i know there is `exec` available in nodejs but i am unable to understand how those php semaphore function will be implemented using nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, might be late, but...here is the link
https://github.com/abrkn/semaphore.js